# PowerShell Invoke-RestMethod cmdlet failing to send second authentication challenge?

Tags: rest, powershell, windows-authentication, sspi

When using PowerShell's `Invoke-RestMethod` to a service that uses Windows Authentication, I'm getting a "401.2 Not Authorized" Exception, but I've confirmed via

```
$currentUser = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name
```

that I'm using the expected user.  I've verified that user is allowed in my service's web.config. Here's my actual invocation:

```
Invoke-RestService -Method "POST" -Uri $serviceApiUri -Body (ConvertTo-Json $body) -UseDefaultCredentials -ContentType "application/json"
```

Anyone else have issues with PowerShell's Invoke-RestMethod with Windows Authentication? How can I fix this?

Comment: May I know the error you are getting? Or could you please post the screenshot? Its a very generic question to answer.

Comment: What version of Windows?